# How to open layer using OpenLayers 2 and GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2

I know it's a very basic question but I've been searching for an answer for over 4 hours and I can't get it to work.

I have GeoServer running locally and I'm trying to open a layer in my browser through OpenLayers 2.

This is the code I have:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>OpenLayers Example</title>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
      <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
        var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
        var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
            "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", {layers: 'nurc:nyc_buildings'}     );
        map.addLayer(wms);
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
      </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I copied everything exactly like the example in the OpenLayers website, only changed the URL for the layer and the layer workspace/name.

I tried changing the url to "localhost:8080/geoserver/nurc/wms" and every other possible combination, and I can't get it to work. All I can see is the "+" and "-" for zooming in and out of the layer, but the layer is blank, and sometimes it shows only pink tiles.

Firebug does not show any errors.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Try adding a projection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your "workspace:layername" combination does not exist.
If you open the OpenLayers Preview in Geoserver you will see the layername as a part of the URL like in this example "nurc:ArcSample":

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/nurc/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=nurc:Arc_Sample&styles=&bbox=-180.0,-90.0,180.0,90.0&width=660&height=330&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers

Just try to use exactly the "workspace:layername" combination that you will find in the OL-Preview-URL.